# Capitalisation of two-word surname in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

I've created the following entry (in Jabref):

```
@ARTICLE{Key,
  author = {Pico Della Mirandola},
  title = {Title of Paper},
  journal = {Working Paper, Institute},
  year = {2013},
  owner = {User},
  timestamp = {2013.08.05}
}
```

That shows the following, however `Mirandola, Pico Della, 2013, Title of Paper, Working Paper, Institute.`, which is no good as the surname has been broken up. After reading [www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94mori.pdf‎](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94mori.pdf%E2%80%8E), I changed the Jabref entry to having a lowercase `della` which keep the surname together: `della Mirandola, Pico, 2013, Title of Paper, Working Paper, Institute.`, but I'm just using this name as an example: the capitalisation in my document. I need it to show `Della Mirandola, Pico, 2013, Title of Paper, Working Paper, Institute.`

I'm sure sure if this approach is using bibtex, biblatex or natbib or whatever, but I have to use a .bst file to format my bibliography as I need to follow a specified format, so I want to continue creating the .bbl file automatically in TexnicCenter like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsart-harv}
\bibliography{C:/jabrefBib}
```

and just citing the references in the document as usual (`\cite{Key}`).
How can I implement a workaround for this to get the surname right?

Comment: `Della Mirandola, Pico` should do.

Comment: Works great. Thanks again. Can't vote for the reply.

Comment: Checked that. Both solutions work: both enclosing the offending surname in curly brackets and just moving to `surname surname, lastname`.